how to use java in compose multiplatform
i have a project crossing the platforms.but there are some codes which is programmed by java and my trying to import java into the compose multiplatform was failed.
just as the title,i want to know how to import java into a compose multiplatform project
I use the builder supported by jetbrains link,and this is my project structure

when i tried to create a source folder of java,there even was no any hint
so i tried to ask the copilot,this is its answer

but the problem is that the "setDir" is a Unresolved function
this is the build.script.kts of my project
import org.jetbrains.compose.ExperimentalComposeLibrary
import org.jetbrains.compose.desktop.application.dsl.TargetFormat



plugins {
    alias(libs.plugins.kotlinMultiplatform)
    alias(libs.plugins.androidApplication)
    alias(libs.plugins.jetbrainsCompose)
}

kotlin {
    androidTarget {
        compilations.all {
            kotlinOptions {
                jvmTarget = "1.8"
            }
        }
    }

    jvm("desktop")

    sourceSets {
        val desktopMain by getting
        androidMain.dependencies {
            implementation(libs.compose.ui.tooling.preview)
            implementation(libs.androidx.activity.compose)
        }
        commonMain.dependencies {
            implementation(compose.runtime)
            implementation(compose.foundation)
            implementation(compose.material)
            implementation(compose.ui)
            @OptIn(ExperimentalComposeLibrary::class)
            implementation(compose.components.resources)
        }
        desktopMain.dependencies {
            implementation(compose.desktop.currentOs)
        }
    }
}

android {
    namespace = "indi.midreamsheep.app.tre"
    compileSdk = libs.versions.android.compileSdk.get().toInt()

    sourceSets["main"].manifest.srcFile("src/androidMain/AndroidManifest.xml")
    sourceSets["main"].res.srcDirs("src/androidMain/res")
    sourceSets["main"].resources.srcDirs("src/commonMain/resources")

    defaultConfig {
        applicationId = "indi.midreamsheep.app.tre"
        minSdk = libs.versions.android.minSdk.get().toInt()
        targetSdk = libs.versions.android.targetSdk.get().toInt()
        versionCode = 1
        versionName = "1.0"
    }
    packaging {
        resources {
            excludes += "/META-INF/{AL2.0,LGPL2.1}"
        }
    }
    buildTypes {
        getByName("release") {
            isMinifyEnabled = false
        }
    }
    compileOptions {
        sourceCompatibility = JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
        targetCompatibility = JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
    }
    dependencies {
        debugImplementation(libs.compose.ui.tooling)
    }
}

compose.desktop {
    application {
        mainClass = "MainKt"

        nativeDistributions {
            targetFormats(TargetFormat.Dmg, TargetFormat.Msi, TargetFormat.Deb)
            packageName = "indi.midreamsheep.app.tre"
            packageVersion = "1.0.0"
        }
    }
}

i want to how to import java into the compose multiplatform

Are you trying to write your own code in Java? Or are you trying to use a Java library?
